# Pro Tools installation : OS X version is "too old"

Tags: macos, mac, installation, osx-el-capitan, pro-tools

I'm trying to install Pro Tools on my late 2012 Macbook Pro running OS X 10.11.6. When the installer checks if I'm running OSX  10.7 or higher, I get an error message stating:

> Pro Tools cannot be installed because the following error(s) were found on your system:
>   - An incompatible version of the OS was found.  Pro Tools 10.3.10 requires Mac OS X version 10.7 or higher.

What can I do to force the installation?

Comment: You would have to upgrade to 10.7.  If you cannot run OS X 10.7 for whatever reason, use a previous version of Pro Tool, that does support 10.6

Comment: That'd be a downgrade right ? I'm using OSX 10.11

Comment: The problem you have is not only does Pro Tools 10.3.10 not support OS X 10.11.6 even the current version has compatiablity problems with it.  I suggest, trying [Pro Tools 12.3](http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/compatibility/Mac-OS-X-10-11-El-Capitan-support-for-Media-Composer-Pro-Tools-Sibelius-EUCON-and-ISIS) just to see if it works or downgrade to OS X 10.11.3

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in a title, just submit an answer, I am rolling the title back.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to install Pro Tools 10.3. Only Pro Tools 12+ supports El Capitan--and only for 10.11.3 and below (see [Avid's official post](http://avid.force.com/pkb/articles/en_US/compatibility/Mac-OS-X-10-11-El-Capitan-support-for-Media-Composer-Pro-Tools-Sibelius-EUCON-and-ISIS)).  I was able to install Pro Tools 12.3 without a problem; however 10.11.4 and above are officially unsupported, and may have bugs.